# Smtp Auth Login

Tags: email, authentication, smtp

I'm trying to send an email via SMTP using telnet. I have to authenticate (I'm interested now in AUTH LOGIN method). Here is output:

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 localhost ESMTP service ready
ehlo localhost
250-localhost
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-PIPELINING
250 8BITMIME
auth login
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
bXl1c2VybmFtZQ
334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
bXlwYXNzd29yZA
535 invalid authentication
```

With example above all is fine - server understands my login and passwords (there are wrong but it's not important right now). Here is another example:

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 localhost ESMTP service ready
ehlo localhost
250-localhost
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-PIPELINING
250 8BITMIME
auth login bXl1c2VybmFtZQ
334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
bXlwYXNzd29yZA
500 Unrecognized command
```

My question is - am I able to send `AUTH LOGIN user_name` command and then password? Or should I always send just `AUTH LOGIN` and then separately user name and separately password?